# Which are the most imperative Craft and Tools in DnD E5?

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting

Sleeping and eating are inevitable parts of every adventurer's life, whether you are doing a mission or you are on downtime.

But there are some other essential needs to be taken care of, like mending your armor or healing wounds. The PHB E5 has provided ome Tools and Kits to use on page 154, such as Artisan Tools, Herbalist Kits, Poisoner's Kit, etc.

Which of these Tools/Kits are imperative to have for staying alive during a journey?

Is it:

- Cook's untensils to make food and drinks to survive?
- Leatherworker's tools to mend your armor when you are on a mission and you won't have any towns on your way for weeks?
- Herbalist's Kit to pick up useful herbs to abolish disease and mend the wounds ?
- Alchemist's supplies to make health potions?
- Is another tool or kit the most important?

Answer (score 4):

Bards cannot choose tool proficiencies for their level 3 feature. You can take the skilled feat at level 4.

The best one is the one you can think of the most uses for for your character.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right! My DM made a house rule that we can learn choose a tool instead of skills whenever we have the chance to get a skill. I forgot its out house rule.